# How do you sketch arcsin(arcsin(x))?

Tags: trigonometry

When I sketch sin(x), arcsin(x) and arcsin(arcsin(x)) on Geogebra, there is a slight difference between the second and third graphs. I thought that perhaps because you're doing an 'inverse of an inverse' that you might get back to the original function but there is something different going on. Can anybody please explain why the gradients are slightly different (endpoints are the same) and how I can show this algebraically?

Comment: "Inverse of an inverse" would be $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ since $\sin$ is the inverse of $\arcsin$. The function $\arcsin(\arcsin(x))$ would be like "inverse twice", and in this case $\arcsin$ is not the inverse of $\arcsin$.

Comment: @Dave Agreed as I thought sin(arcsin(x)) would give the line y=x on the graph. I guess I want to know how to go about sketching this using algebra to help me visualise it :)

Comment: Indeed, $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ will give the line $y=x$ (restricted to the appropriate domain). However, sketching $\arcsin(\arcsin(x))$ is more difficult to do by hand. One observation: if you know how to sketch $\arcsin(x)$, then for small values of $x$ we have $\arcsin(x)\approx x$, so $\arcsin(\arcsin(x))$ roughly looks like $\arcsin(x)$ for small $x$, and curves away slightly as $x$ gets bigger.

Comment: @Dave you're right it is tricky but one of my students asked what's going algebraically and it'd be great to point them in the right direction at least :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have them compute the Taylor series as far as they want.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20arcsin(arcsin(x))) gives
$$x + x^3/3 + (7 x^5)/30 + (64 x^7)/315 + (4477 x^9)/22680 + (28447 x^{11})/138600 + O(x^{12})$$  I think the intuitive terms are the first two.  We know $\arcsin x \approx x$ and the correction is $+\frac {x^3}6$, so taking two arcsins should give twice the correction.

Comment: Thank you! I was kinda hoping for an intuitive visualisation, perhaps using the unit circle and y=sqrt(1-x^2) and doing some sort of compound function like f(f(x)). Do you have any idea if that is something worth investigating because I'm not finding much on it at the mo...

Comment: I don't think so.  I am basically using the chain rule, $(f(f(x)))'=f'(f(x))f'(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Of *course* $\sin^{-1} x$ and $\sin^{-1} (\sin^{-1} x)$ have different slopes:  they are different functions!

You know the latter goes through $(-\pi/4, -\pi/2)$, $(0,0)$ and $(\pi/4, \pi/2)$ and is monotonically increasing and antisymmetric.  That gets you close.

But why not just plot it?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input. I plotted the graphs out which was easy enough and yes, I can get values by putting them into the calculator. I guess what I'm trying to determine is an intuitive explanation as to what is going on 'in the background'. I'm referring to the change in domains and ranges, the different gradients (yes I've differentiated to show the different functions) and maybe trying to use the unit circle to help algebraically. How do you solve arcsin(arcsin(x)) = 0 for example to get the values you mentioned. Arcos(arcos(x)) is very different for example. Waffling now!